# Any work on Scala that is similar to WebSharper

Tags: javascript, scala, f#, websharper

I was reading some articles from here: http://tomasp.net/blog/qcon-async-fsharp.aspx, about having all the source code in F# that would then compile to generate the javascript, so it can do asynchronous calls back to the server, and the server-side code, with the advantage that everything was strongly typed before anything was generated, and the client-side is always kept in sync with the server-side, since both are generated at the same time.

There is this blog also, that gives a bit more information.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2012/01/22/websharper-javascript-html5-mobile-etc.aspx

If F# can generate this, I am curious if anyone has worked on having Scala do this also.

Answer (score 2):

- more or less working should be:

scalagwt: http://scalagwt.github.com/
but this goes through the gwt tool chain.

- more in line withou your request but a prototype is:

play2.0 with DSL scala for validation that compiles to JS:

http://www.infoq.com/interviews/amin-scala

https://github.com/namin/play-js-validation

Comment: I will play with this framework and see what I think, thank you.  I am not crazy about it having to compile to Scala, and I am thinking that there may be a better approach, as I really like the F# approach, as all the coding is done in F#, so you automatically get the strong typing, and you can have functions that can work on the client or server-side, and where you have to have client code you can't accidentally put server functionality.